# Не выводит русские символы в модуле

Tags: php

Модуль комментариев в профиле.
Сообщение с русскими символами выводится пустое, а с латиницей нормально. Перепробовал разные версии везде тоже самое, помогите.

кодировка сайта Windows-1251

Все файлы модуля Windows-1251

таблица в базе тоже cp1251_general_ci

Кусок кода в модуле отвечающий за кодировку

```
if ($_POST['ajax'] == 1)
    {
    function echoReturn($text)
        {
        die("<script language=\"javascript\">alert('{$text}');</script>");
        }

    if (!function_exists("CharsetConvert"))
        {
        function CharsetConvert($text, $to = "auto")
            {
            global $config;
            if (version_compare($config['version_id'], "7.5", "<")) return convert_unicode($text);
            $text = stripslashes($text);
            $charset = mb_detect_encoding($text, "utf-8,windows-1251");
            if ($to == "auto") $to = $config['charset'];
            if ($charset != $to && $to != "") $text = iconv($charset, $to . "//IGNORE", $text);
            return urldecode($text);
            }
        }

    if (!$is_logged) die($lang["lang_wall_1"]);
    $UserID = intval($member_id['user_id']);
    $UserName = stripslashes($member_id['name']);
    if ($_POST['add'] == 1)
        {
        $text = trim(htmlspecialchars(CharsetConvert(stripslashes($_POST['text']))));
```

Comment: Проверьте базу данных, она должна поддерживать инкодинг при подключении

Comment: Как проверить базу?

Comment: @steep, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом приведённый кусок кода относится к выводу комментариев? приведённый кусок кода насколько понимаю декодирует пришедшие по XHR(аяксу) комментарии.Самый простой способ - подключиться к БД и посмотреть что лежит в базе и определить где проблема: при сохранении комментариев или при их выводе.

Comment: В базе комментария тоже нет. Где можно весь код написать, он не маленький?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо явно указывать кодировку (третьим параметром).

Последняя строка в моём коде, меняем на эту.

```
$text = trim(htmlspecialchars(CharsetConvert(stripslashes($_POST['text'])), ENT_COMPAT, "windows-1251"));
```